# Non-diagonalizable matrix and nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra

Is every non-diagonalizable matrix nilpotent? I know that the converse is true, but I don't know how to prove this is true.

Comment: Rotations of $\mathbb R^2$ through an angle that isn’t a multiple of $\pi/4$ are neither diagonalizable (over the reals) nor nilpotent.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, the following matrix is non-diagonalizable but not nilpotent (since it is invertible).

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

What is true is that every non-diagonalizable matrix is the sum between a diagonalizable matrix and a nilpotent. This is easy to prove if you know the Jordan Canonical form of a matrix: it is trivial to write the Jordan Canonical Form as the sum of a diagonal matrix and a nilpotent.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true.  For example: if $A$ is nilpotent, then $A + I$ is neither nilpotent nor diagonalizable ($I$ is the identity matrix).  For a concrete example,
$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}
$$
is neither nilpotent nor diagonalizable.